# Should we open this site to include SEM, IM questions?

Tags: discussion

I am keeping this question intentionally simple so please forgive me if it appears too simple.

Should Pro Webmasters include within it's scope, questions about SEM (search engine marketing) and IM (internet marketing)?

I am thinking that these topics are related to SEO and a part of the daily webmaster task list.

The difficulty would be defining the scope of the question to solicit factual answers. This could be limited to known or existing web marketing methods, tactics and application examples.

I am bringing this up for discussion.

Please include (as much as you can) some idea of scope so that the questions do not get too wild. The Mods have enough to do.

Comment: We certainly have lots of SEM questions here already.  Bidding and AdWords is directly related to running your website and getting traffic for it.

Comment: Would internet marketing include email marketing?   Email marketing would be on-topic if it were related to marketing a website, but would be off-topic in cases in which it doesn't involve a website.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Good points. I was thinking more in the order of actual marketing and application of marketing techniques for engagement, conversion, and so on. There are quite a few techniques regarding how to capture interest and how to make something compelling and conversion. While I know a fair amount about this, I find that I actually do not practice it enough and I suspect that there is a lot we can learn by opening up a bit. I was not sure how to define scope for something like this. That is why I left it open. I am more mad scientist and not always very imaginative. ;-)

Comment: While I personally regard that stuff as noise, I do see that it is within the scope of being a webmaster and agree with the comments from  @StephenOstermiller

Comment: @Steve FYI: The genesis of this question was the question http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/73963/what-are-the-next-steps-i-should-take-to-market-my-website being put on hold as being off-topic when in fact, the question was about things we do everyday. I am not talking about anything so far off topic, but more complimentary to what could be an appropriate question. I think perhaps the terms SEM and IM are seen as separated from SEO but in reality, I see it more as SEO separate from keywords and tags and such. We already get into some of it, but perhaps not enough.

Comment: I think John used the wrong close reason on that question, or at least didn't adequately explain what was wrong.  I would have closed that question as "too broad".  It isn't the subject matter that is off-topic, it is the request for recommendations.  I'll put an additional comment on that question.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I agree with the closing and recognized the other problems with the question. I was not criticizing/questioning the closing at all; I was just saying it was the genesis of the question. I recognize that my statement could have been made better. It was just the spark.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this site already picks up all marketing related questions on the SE network.

Currently, most, if not all, would get pinged across to Webmasters SE. I don't think that needs to change although it is probably worth noting the current running Area 51 proposed new sites on SE [digital marketing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65811/digital-marketing) and [marketing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75798/marketing).

We've got to be wary of overlap, and there is plenty of that in digital services. Right now, minimal overlap is caused as the Webmasters SE pretty much covers it all. As soon as we start seeing SE sites for digital marketing, SEO, conversions, web design (etc), it would not be long before it becomes very confusing what questions are best suited to which SE sites. The only ones that could easily (in most cases) escape this is probably paid search and analytics.

Anyhow, that's my two bobs worth.

Comment: I forgot about Area 51! You are right. Perhaps another new site specific to digital marketing is in order. I did think about overlap. A was not thinking purely marketing. Marketing types can really run off in some directions we have no idea about. Trust me. And in retrospect, I am not sure I am seeing people wanting anything other than a technical answer here. I think for noobs, using my h1 tag example, I could weave some ideas in, but I guess for the bulk of it, it would not be that natural order for this site. Thanks for your two bobs!

Answer (score 0):

This site is already to open to search engine marketing  and internet marketing questions as long as they are related to a website that you run.  Examples:

- [How to make adwords autobidding bid separately on each keyword](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/71498/how-to-make-adwords-autobidding-bid-separately-on-each-keyword)
- [Web marketing: tangible advantages of being on Twitter?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2408/web-marketing-tangible-advantages-of-being-on-twitter)
- [As an affiliate, how do you know if a sale is made?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35230/as-an-affiliate-how-do-you-know-if-a-sale-is-made)

[This question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/73963/what-are-the-next-steps-i-should-take-to-market-my-website) was closed as off topic not because it relates to marketing, but because questions asking for recommendations are off topic.

Comment: Again, I was not in disagreement with the closing and recognized that the reason was not directly due to it being a marketing question. It just was a spark. I guess the real answer is, we just don't really get questions that are more marketing and less technical and that is that. I was thinking marketing related as opposed to technical questions mostly because the marketing site is now gone. For example, Is there a recommended sentence structure for link tag text to increase current CTR to a free e-book? Or, How do I apply a cascading block-method to related page topic keywords?

Comment: increasing CTR to your website would be on-topic, but not an eBook.

Comment: I do not mean questions regarding an e-book, but how to motivate a user to follow a link to an e-book, or encourage sign-ups, or to read an article, etc. In this case, there are specific sentence structures and motivational methods that would answer the question per case. It is still a technical question, just not HTML, CSS, JavaScript technical. It is marketing technical. Again, I just do not think we get enough of these questions and it may be hard to frame limitations on this. I just thought perhaps we could encourage thinking of SEO in new ways without getting too deep.